# Android - Wait for DialogFragment response

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a dialog fragment and a button with an action listener. Whenever the button is clicked I do the following

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new myConfirmDialog();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),
                            "confirmAction");
// wait here till user responds to the fragment
if(newFragment.returnedTrue){

function1(); // random function to be executed afterwards. 

}else if(newFragment.returnedFalse){

    function2(); // random function to be executed afterwards.

}
```

The dialog fragment displays just about fine, however how do I wait till the user finishes entering data to then proceed with the rest of the function calls after the show() function.

I couldn't find anything relevant online.

Comment: however how do I wait till the user finishes entering data ?? what you mean about that?

Comment: ok so I display a dialog that asks user to enter some text. how do I wait till the user hits the SUBMIT button to continue the program flow.

Comment: can you post more code where you want to pause the program

Comment: I hope its more clear now Rod, let me know what you think.